# Function to generate analytic solution of StandardDeviation of a list given sublists

Tags: probability-or-statistics, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

## Motivation

I have the `Mean` and `StandardDeviation` of several lists of equal size but I don't know the elements of those lists.

I want to find what the `Mean` and `StandardDeviation` would be if I combined those lists together.

The `Mean` of the combined lists is trivial, but I am finding the `StandardDeviation` more complicated...

I am not very confident in the use of `Solve` especially with statistical functions and so could use some help

---

## Problem

Let `r` be a list of real numbers of length `m`, where `m` is an even number. *(`r` is the combined list from above)*

`r` is partitioned into `x` sublists of equal length where `x` is an even number. (Call them `r1`, `r2`,...,`rx`.  The length of each `ri` is `n`).

How can I generate a function,`f`, that generates the analytic solution that finds the `StandardDeviation` of `r`, given only:

- the `Mean[r]` (call it `u`)
- the `Mean` of each sublist,`Mean[r1]`,`Mean[r2]`...(Call it`u1`,`u2`...)
- and the `StandardDeviation` of each sublist, `StandardDeviation[r1]`,`StandardDeviation[r2]`...(Call it `s1`, `s1`...)

**ie. I want to find a function `g[x_]` that generates `f`**

---

## Example

eg. we can solve this by hand for `x=2` which gives

```
f[n_,u_,{s1_, s2_}, {u1_, u2_}] := 
 Sqrt[(((n - 1)*(s1^2 + s2^2)) + n*(u1^2 + u2^2) - 2*n*u^2)/(2*n - 1)]
```

Check formula on an example

```
SeedRandom[1];
m = 100;
n = m/2;
r = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, m];
r1 = r[[;; n]];
r2 = r[[n + 1 ;;]];

u = Mean[r];
u1 = Mean[r1];
u2 = Mean[r2];

s1 = StandardDeviation[r1];
s2 = StandardDeviation[r2];

StandardDeviation[r] == f[n, u, {u1, u2}, {s1, s2}];
```

> True

Comment: It turns out this can be solved by "The exact pooled variance is the mean of the variances plus the variance of the means of the component data sets." from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4567292/1221434. 

The original paper is "Calculating the Exact Pooled Variance
J. W. Rudmin, Physics Dept., James Madison University" https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1007/1007.1012.pdf

Comment: I am still interested in seeing if we can use Mathematica to solve this problem

Comment: The STD is the square root of the variance. The variance of a sum x+y is var(x+y)= var(x)+var(y)+2 cov[x,y], where cov is the covariance. If x and y are independent, the covariance is zero.

Comment: The general formula is not restricted to even numbers of groups.  `m` can be even or odd.

Comment: Note that the referenced paper uses a definition of variance where one divides by the sample size rather than the sample size minus 1.  That's not necessarily wrong but *Mathematica* divides by the sample size minus 1.  Which do you want?  Also that referenced paper uses the term "pooled" in a non-standard way.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to do so.  Note that this is a data manipulation exercise and doesn't imply any ability to make inferences with the resulting standard deviation.

```
m = 5; (* Number of groups *)
n = 7;  (* Sample size per group *)
(* Random sample of size n from m normal distributions *) 
r = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {m, n}];
sd = StandardDeviation[#] & /@ r
(* {1.12549, 0.827586, 0.762233, 0.973844, 0.84024} *)
mean = Mean[#] & /@ r
(* {-0.145108, -0.0999453, -0.788001, 0.43927, -0.303919} *)

(* Overall mean by formula *)
overallMean = Total[mean]/m
(* -0.179541 *)
(* Overall mean from raw data *)
Mean[Flatten[r]]
(* -0.179541 *)

(* Overall standard deviation by formula *)
Sqrt[(Total[sd^2 (n - 1) + n mean^2] - n m (Total[mean]/m)^2)/(n m - 1)]
(* Total sums of squares minus total number of observations*square of 
   overall mean divided by total sample size minus 1 *)
(* 0.947985 *)
(* Standard deviation from raw data *)
StandardDeviation[Flatten[r]]
(* 0.947985 *)
```

Putting all of this into a single function:

```
g[n_, mean_, sd_] := {Mean[mean], 
  Sqrt[(Total[sd^2 (n - 1) + n mean^2] - n Length[mean] Mean[mean]^2)/(n Length[mean] - 1)]}

g[n, mean, sd]
(* {-0.179541, 0.947985} *)
```